# How to get a value from a procedure in java

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, plsql

I have a stored procedure that returns a value 0 or 1

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "MYPROC"   (KEY in NUMBER,
                                    VAR out NUMBER)
```

...

I call my procedure in hava using the following code (which is working fine):

```
SimpleJdbcCall simpleJdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(DataSource);
simpleJdbcCall.withProcedureName("CPF_DTW.MYPROC");

simpleJdbcCall.withoutProcedureColumnMetaDataAccess();
simpleJdbcCall.declareParameters(new SqlParameter("KEY", Types.NUMERIC));

Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>(2);
parameters.put("KEY", actionKey);
simpleJdbcCall.execute(parameters);
```

Now after the execution of the proc, I need to access and get the value that the procudere as in the output parameter **VAR**, can you please help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The execute of SimpleJdbcCall returns a map which contains key-value pairs of the output parameters.

For example, you can retrieve the output parameter VAR in the following way:

```
 Map outputMap = simpleJdbcCall.execute(parameters);
 System.out.println((String)outputMap.get("VAR"));
```

Comment: this is not working! this will crush :\  can anyone help me ?